# Двойное условие определения логического вектора&неверная инверсия

Tags: r

Задание:

Создайте логический вектор even_caps, в котором будет TRUE, если в векторе num записано четное число, а в векторе chr стоит заглавная английская буква. Помните, все буквы английского алфавита можно найти во встроенных векторах LETTERS и letters.

Дано:

> num <- c(12, 8, 11, 16, 7, 24, 1, 4, 3, 24, 21, 16, 20, 11, 19, 28,
>   28, 15, 30, 17, 17, 1, 9, 25, 30, 20, 26, 8, 18, 21, 3)
>
> chr <-
>   c('T','h','e','F','i','v','e','B','o','x','i','n','g','W','i','z','a','r','d','s','J','u','m','p','Q','u','i','c','k','l','y')

Решение:

> even_caps=(chr %in% LETTERS)&(rev(as.logical(num%%2)))
>
> Failed. Wrong answer

**Почему?**

Хотелось бы уточнить про

> as.logical(num%%2))

- код выполняет поиск четных чисел. Однако код

> rev(as.logical(num%%2)))

выдает последовательность ОТЛИЧНУЮ от обратной as.logical(num%%2)).

> as.logical(num%%2) 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
>   0 0 0 1 1
>
> rev(as.logical(num%%2)) 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
>   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0

**Почему так?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос в понимании слова «обратный». В данном случае нужен не `rev`, а логическое отрицание — `!`, чтобы обратить в векторе ложь в истину и наоборот. `rev` просто возвращает вектор в обратном порядке.

```
rev(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Вариант с логическим отрицанием:

```
num <- c(12, 8, 11, 16, 7, 24, 1, 4, 3, 24, 21, 16, 20, 11, 19, 28, 28, 15, 30, 17, 17, 1, 9, 25, 30, 20, 26, 8, 18, 21, 3)

chr <- c('T','h','e','F','i','v','e','B','o','x','i','n','g','W','i','z','a','r','d','s','J','u','m','p','Q','u','i','c','k','l','y')

even_caps <- (chr %in% LETTERS) & (!(as.logical(num %% 2)))
# TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE ...
```

UPD: Конечно, вариант **selesnow** проще и понятнее, и я бы предпочел именно его. Но вопрос был про инверсию.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
even_caps <- (num %% 2 == 0) & (chr %in% LETTERS)
```

```r
num <- c(12, 8, 11, 16, 7, 24, 1, 4, 3, 24, 21, 16, 20, 11, 19, 28, 28, 15, 30, 17, 17, 1, 9, 25, 30, 20, 26, 8, 18, 21, 3)

chr <- c('T','h','e','F','i','v','e','B','o','x','i','n','g','W','i','z','a','r','d','s','J','u','m','p','Q','u','i','c','k','l','y')

even_caps <- (num %% 2 == 0) & (chr %in% LETTERS)

print(even_caps)
#>  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [12] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [23] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>